# How do I actually BOND a device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, device

Everywhere I look I find this method "getBondedDevices()" for my bluetooth adapter. However, I have my tablet and another bluetooth device sitting next to me, and I can't figure out how to actually get the device to show up on the list of bonded devices.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Bluetooth terms, "bonded" and "paired" are basically synonyms (officially, the process of pairing leads to a bond, but most people use them interchangeable).  In order for your device to be added to that list, you must go through the process of **Discovery**, which is how one device searches and finds another, and then **Pair** the two together.

You can actually do this from the device settings as a user, but if you are looking to so so within the context of an app, your process will likely look something like this:

1. Register a `BroadcastReceiver` for `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND` and `BluetoothAdapter. ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED`
2. Start discovery by calling `BluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery()`
3. Your receiver will get called with the first action every time a new device is found in range, and you can inspect it to see if it's the one you want to connect with.  You can call `BluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery()` once you've found it to not waste the battery any more than necessary.
4. When discovery is complete, if you haven't canceled it, your receiver will get called with the second action; so you know not to expect any more devices.
5. With a device instance in hand, open a `BluetoothSocket` and `connect()`.  If the devices are not already bonded, this will initiate pairing and may show some system UI for a PIN code.
6. Once paired, your device will show up in the bonded devices list until the user goes into settings and removes it.
7. The `connect()` method also actually opens the socket link, and when it returns without throwing an exception the two devices are connected.
8. Now connected, you can call `getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()` from the socket to read and write data.

Basically, you can inspect the list of bonded devices to quickly get access to an external device, but in most applications you will be doing a combination of this and true discovery to make sure you can always connect to the remote device regardless of what the user does.  If a device is already bonded, you'd just be doing steps 5-7 to connect and communicate.

For more information and sample code, check out the "Discovering Devices" and "Connecting Devices" sections of the [Android SDK Bluetooth Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html).

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot that really helped. I am currently stuck at step number 5 though. In my onReceive method I add the devices found to a list, but thats as far as I have gotten. I am looking for docs on a BluetoothSocket constructor but haven't found any yet. Do I simply create an object, call the 'connect()' function on it, then the devices will appear in my list of bonded devices? The devices found are in  an ArrayAdapter<String> data structure, I'm having trouble grasping the idea that calling connect() on a new object will do everything for me.

Comment: If you read the dev guide that I linked to, you'll notice in the connecting example that the method `createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()` is used to generate the socket object off the device.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I have looked through the guide and I just get a little confused still. I am using a phone/tablet to connect to another bluetooth device which is NOT a phone/tablet. This may seem trivial but I haven't been able to convince myself I understand it, when I add a BluetoothSocket to my object, my phone/tablet acts as a server, correct? I am also confused at it says call 'connect()' to start listening for devices, but I have already found the device and have its address. What exactly would it be listening for?

Comment: What's really confusing me the most is that the device I'm connecting to has no interface, its simply a circuit board with information I want to retrieve. The guide says


     "The server and client are considered connected to each other when they each have a connected BluetoothSocket on the same RFCOMM channel."

Comment: It depends a little on how your embedded device is set up, but most embedded Bluetooth modems accept incoming connections (making them the server) by default.  The Android device would be a client, calling `connect()` as in the "Connecting as a client" example of the guide.  When `connect()` returns successfully you can use `getInputStream()` and `getOutputStream()` to start transferring data.

Comment: Sorry I'm still pretty confused, the 'createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord()' is of type 'BluetoothDevice', but I do not have a 'BluetoothDevice' initialized yet. From what I understand, I have my 'BluetoothAdapter' on my device, then a 'BluetoothSocket' must be initialized for my device, which then connects to the other device which is a 'BluetoothDevice'. Do I need to make all three 'BluetoothAdapter', 'BluetoothDevice', and 'BluetoothSocket' objects for my device?

Comment: You get the `BluetoothDevice` either from `getBondedDevices()` (if already paired) or from the `BroadcastReceiver` callback during discovery when that device is found.  In the latter case, the device itself is passed back as an extra in the `Intent` handed to the `onReceive()` method.

Comment: Hey, I don't know if you'll still answer this. But I'm actually still stuck at the end of this and no one has answered my other questions. 

I set myBtDevice equal to the address the user clicks on. Then, I set myBtSocket equal to myBtDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord( MY_UUID). 

After that, when I call btSocket.connect(), an IO error arises and the program crashes.

I have the address of the device I want to connect to, but when I call connect it fails.

Comment: I will look at and answer your other questions, this thread has gotten too long.

Answer (score 3):

API level 19 and above you can call createBond() on BluetoothDevice instace to which you want to connect.
You will require some permissions to discover and list the visible devices

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Code to discover and list the devices:

```
bluetoothFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
bluetoothFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
bluetoothFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, bluetoothFilter);
private BroadcastReceiver bluetoothReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                Log.e("bluetoothReceiver", "ACTION_FOUND");
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                devicesList.add((device.getName() != null ? device.getName() : device.getAddress()));
                bluetoothDevicesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
                Log.e("bluetoothReceiver", "ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED");
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                Log.e("bluetoothReceiver", "ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED");
                getActivity().unregisterReceiver(bluetoothReceiver);
            }
        }
};
```

Just call createBond() on selected device.