# android bluetooth, what is the difference between bonded and paired

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am busy with an android project in eclipse to connect my Samsung galaxy s4 with bluetooth to a random  other Bluetooth device. I want to start with an HTC incredible s.

My question is: what is the difference between bonded and paired.
Because android say that it is the same, but in my application they are not acting the same.

I have red that when you startDiscovery(). you can see all paired devices. 
that works fine, but if I call device.getBondState(); then it tels that the device is not bonded.

And if the device is not bonded I can not connect to the device.

Comment: useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937387/how-do-i-actually-bond-a-device